# How to select specific P elements inside a div with several divs inside?

Tags: html, css

There is a div with class "animationbg" that contains several other divs, as shown in the code below. Inside "animationbg" there are 5 paragraphs. I wanted to select each of them separately using nth-of-type() or nth-child() however I can't do it.

```
   <div id="section-id-1622707595290" class="sppb-section animationbg">
        <div class="sppb-container-inner">
            <div class="sppb-row">
                <div class="sppb-col-md-12" id="column-wrap-id-1622707595291">
                    <div id="column-id-1622707595291" class="sppb-column">
                        <div class="sppb-column-addons">
                            <div id="sppb-addon-wrapper-1622707595289" class="sppb-addon-wrapper">
                                <div id="sppb-addon-1622707595289" class="clearfix ">
                                    <div class="sppb-addon sppb-addon-raw-html warerocket">
                                        <div class="sppb-addon-content"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="sppb-addon-wrapper-1622707595314" class="sppb-addon-wrapper">
                                <div id="sppb-addon-1622707595314" class="clearfix ">
                                    <div class="sppb-addon sppb-addon-raw-html mttitle">
                                        <div class="sppb-addon-content">
                                            <p>Meta tag TITLE</p>
                                            <p>Meta tag TITLE 2</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="sppb-addon-wrapper-1622707595323" class="sppb-addon-wrapper">
                                <div id="sppb-addon-1622707595323" class="clearfix ">
                                    <div class="sppb-addon sppb-addon-raw-html mtdesc">
                                        <div class="sppb-addon-content">
                                            <p>Meta tag<br>DESCRIPTION</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="sppb-addon-wrapper-1622707595336" class="sppb-addon-wrapper">
                                <div id="sppb-addon-1622707595336" class="clearfix ">
                                    <div class="sppb-addon sppb-addon-raw-html mth">
                                        <div class="sppb-addon-content">
                                            <p>h1 h2 h3</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="sppb-addon-wrapper-1622707595349" class="sppb-addon-wrapper">
                                <div id="sppb-addon-1622707595349" class="clearfix ">
                                    <div class="sppb-addon sppb-addon-raw-html mturlr">
                                        <div class="sppb-addon-content">
                                            <p>URL Rewrite</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="sppb-addon-wrapper-1622707595358" class="sppb-addon-wrapper">
                                <div id="sppb-addon-1622707595358" class="clearfix ">
                                    <div class="sppb-addon sppb-addon-raw-html sitemap">
                                        <div class="sppb-addon-content">
                                            <p>Sitemap</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean, when you say "select"? Are you writing a CSS selector or do you parse that data with XPATH maybe? Please try to specify the goal, which you are trying to achieve (what should be the desired selection, what do you want to do with that selection, why is it exactly that selection?)

Comment: Thats not working because each paragraph is the first and only child-element of the "sppb-addon-content" div (exept for the case with 2 paragraphs **).

Comment: Why don't you use the existing classes (mttitle, mtdesc, mth, mturlr) to select the individual paragraphs? Like this `.animationbg .mtdesc .p`

Comment: @lupz yes, I know I could have used those classes, however I wanted to be able to just select all P inside a div regardless of how many divs are nested. The answer below of Haworth seems to be the one applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without needing to alter the HTML. The paragraphs are within divs which are within divs etc up to where you can start to select the containing div by its nth child position.

Of course, you'll have to be aware that if the HTML structure changes the CSS selector will have to change (e.g. if another empty set of divs is put above).

This snippet just changes the background color of the p elements. Note I have left the child(1) selectors in even where they are in the given case redundant just in case extra p elements are loaded in there at any point.

[image]

```css
.sppb-addon-wrapper:nth-child(2) p:nth-child(1){
  background-color: pink;
}

.sppb-addon-wrapper:nth-child(2) p:nth-child(2){
  background-color: yellow;
}

.sppb-addon-wrapper:nth-child(3) p:nth-child(1){
  background-color: lime;
}

.sppb-addon-wrapper:nth-child(4) p:nth-child(1){
  background-color: cyan;
}

.sppb-addon-wrapper:nth-child(5) p:nth-child(1){
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.sppb-addon-wrapper:nth-child(6) p:nth-child(1){
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
 <div id="section-id-1622707595290" class="sppb-section animationbg">
        <div class="sppb-container-inner">
            <div class="sppb-row">
                <div class="sppb-col-md-12" id="column-wrap-id-1622707595291">
                    <div id="column-id-1622707595291" class="sppb-column">
                        <div class="sppb-column-addons">
                        
                        
                            <div id="sppb-addon-wrapper-1622707595289" class="sppb-addon-wrapper">
                                <div id="sppb-addon-1622707595289" class="clearfix ">
                                    <div class="sppb-addon sppb-addon-raw-html warerocket">
                                        <div class="sppb-addon-content"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                            
                            <div id="sppb-addon-wrapper-1622707595314" class="sppb-addon-wrapper">
                                <div id="sppb-addon-1622707595314" class="clearfix ">
                                    <div class="sppb-addon sppb-addon-raw-html mttitle">
                                        <div class="sppb-addon-content">
                                            <p>Meta tag TITLE</p>
                                            <p>Meta tag TITLE 2</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                            
                            <div id="sppb-addon-wrapper-1622707595323" class="sppb-addon-wrapper">
                                <div id="sppb-addon-1622707595323" class="clearfix ">
                                    <div class="sppb-addon sppb-addon-raw-html mtdesc">
                                        <div class="sppb-addon-content">
                                            <p>Meta tag<br>DESCRIPTION</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                            
                            <div id="sppb-addon-wrapper-1622707595336" class="sppb-addon-wrapper">
                                <div id="sppb-addon-1622707595336" class="clearfix ">
                                    <div class="sppb-addon sppb-addon-raw-html mth">
                                        <div class="sppb-addon-content">
                                            <p>h1 h2 h3</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                            
                            <div id="sppb-addon-wrapper-1622707595349" class="sppb-addon-wrapper">
                                <div id="sppb-addon-1622707595349" class="clearfix ">
                                    <div class="sppb-addon sppb-addon-raw-html mturlr">
                                        <div class="sppb-addon-content">
                                            <p>URL Rewrite</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                            
                            <div id="sppb-addon-wrapper-1622707595358" class="sppb-addon-wrapper">
                                <div id="sppb-addon-1622707595358" class="clearfix ">
                                    <div class="sppb-addon sppb-addon-raw-html sitemap">
                                        <div class="sppb-addon-content">
                                            <p>Sitemap</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have added just id of div1, div2, div3, div4 and div5 in the div preceding p and then added color to every selected p and div, as you can see in the code-

```css
#div1 p:nth-child(1){
color: #2689eb;
}
#div1 p:nth-child(2){
color: #e4eb26;
}
#div2 p/*you can use nth-child() to select different paragraphs*/{
color: #000;
}
#div3 p{
color: #f0118f;
}
#div4 p{
color: #11f018;
}
#div5 p{
color: #11f0e5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="section-id-1622707595290" class="sppb-section animationbg"><div class="sppb-container-inner"><div class="sppb-row"><div class="sppb-col-md-12" id="column-wrap-id-1622707595291"><div id="column-id-1622707595291" class="sppb-column"><div class="sppb-column-addons"><div id="sppb-addon-wrapper-1622707595289" class="sppb-addon-wrapper"><div id="sppb-addon-1622707595289" class="clearfix "><div class="sppb-addon sppb-addon-raw-html warerocket"><div class="sppb-addon-content"></div></div></div></div><div id="sppb-addon-wrapper-1622707595314" class="sppb-addon-wrapper"><div id="sppb-addon-1622707595314" class="clearfix "><div class="sppb-addon sppb-addon-raw-html mttitle"><div id="div1" class="sppb-addon-content"><p>Meta tag TITLE</p>
<p>Meta tag TITLE 2</p></div></div></div></div><div id="sppb-addon-wrapper-1622707595323" class="sppb-addon-wrapper"><div id="sppb-addon-1622707595323" class="clearfix "><div class="sppb-addon sppb-addon-raw-html mtdesc"><div id="div2" class="sppb-addon-content"><p>Meta tag<br>DESCRIPTION</p></div></div></div></div><div id="sppb-addon-wrapper-1622707595336" class="sppb-addon-wrapper"><div id="sppb-addon-1622707595336" class="clearfix "><div class="sppb-addon sppb-addon-raw-html mth"><div id="div3" class="sppb-addon-content"><p>h1 h2 h3</p></div></div></div></div><div id="sppb-addon-wrapper-1622707595349" class="sppb-addon-wrapper"><div id="sppb-addon-1622707595349" class="clearfix "><div class="sppb-addon sppb-addon-raw-html mturlr"><div id="div4" class="sppb-addon-content"><p>URL Rewrite</p></div></div></div></div><div id="sppb-addon-wrapper-1622707595358" class="sppb-addon-wrapper"><div id="sppb-addon-1622707595358" class="clearfix "><div class="sppb-addon sppb-addon-raw-html sitemap"><div id="div5" class="sppb-addon-content"><p>Sitemap</p></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
</body>
</html>
```